# Form updation based on users choice from combobox

Tags: c#, windows

I am making an application where the user has to choose a value from a combobox. Based on the users choice the form should be filled with relevant labels and textboxes. How do I achieve this?

One way I think this could be achieved is by creating all labels and textboxes, and based on the users choice hide the irrelevant ones. But this seems to be very cumbersome. Is there any neat way to do it?

Comment: The first step is to try.

Comment: This question does rely on opinion to a certain degree.  It also depends on exactly what needs to be displayed for each selection.  It might be best to add all possible controls to the form and then hide and show as required.  It might also be best to design a user control for each selection and then add an instance of the appropriate control to the form for the selection.

Comment: Or just creating another form. You can also take a look at `MDI Windows Forms` which may come in handy.

Comment: There are too many ways.

Comment: Could you just give me leads from where I could pick up the many ways? @Jumpei

Comment: Think, Don't google, it's just your job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could you just give me leads from where I could pick up the many
>   ways? @Jumpei –  user2276910 8 mins ago

Just you know, everything in the comments was a lead of some kind. Whichever approach you chose, showing/hiding data is essential. Your combobox selection is a private case. Much more frequently, you gonna need/use this to handle user access so there is no way you gonna start building your application and at some point discover that you can't show/hide data or controls. That's just not the case. In fact since each approach will give you that option, to get a concrete answer will require a lot more information about the project itself and the overall architecture than just this one particular form.

Having said that I will suggest you approach which I think is not the best one, but very intuitive and at some point when you feel more confident you change this.

So in order to achieve this create the form setting the default visibility to all elements. Adding/removing controls dynamically is not that trivial but setting the visibility option is pretty straight forward so I think it's better to start by using the visibility option.

When you are ready with the default state of the form you gonna need few methods. First, an event handler for the combobox select which should be something like this:

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;

    string userSelection = (string)ComboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

From now on you should make a few things. First check if the `userSelection` is something valid. This check is essential, after you are sure that this is valid selection you gonna proceed (and we are still in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event) by calling a a method :

```
private void SetControlsToDefault()
{

}
```

This method will contains all your controls with their default visibility status. That's required because when the user make more than one selection with the combobox if we don't hide the once that were shown on the previous selection you will end up with visible controls when they should be hidden for the certain selection.

So once we are sure that the form is returned to it's initial state we need to check what exactly has the user selected and show the relevant controls.

Here some would suggest to use `switch` I'll suggest `if-else if` statements since I think this will make it more understandable but you can change it if you like so again in the event handler after calling `SetControlsToDefault();` we have this:

```
if (userSelection.Equals("selection1"))
{
  ShowControlsForSelectionOne();
}
else if (userSelection.Equals("selection2"))
{
  ShowControlsForSelectionTwo();
}
else if (userSelection.Equals("selection3"))
{
  ShowControlsForSelectionThree();
}
```

where `ShowControlsForSelectionOne()`, `ShowControlsForSelectionTwo()`, `ShowControlsForSelectionThree()` are all private methods where you gonna set the visibility only to those elements relevant to the selection. And that should be all. This is one of the many ways to complete this task.